# Set notation for the "in which" operation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint sets (i.e. $A \cap B = \varnothing$), define $C = \{A, B\}$, and let $x$ be some value.

What is the operation that it will tell me which subset of $C$, if any, contains $x$?

Possible answers are $x \in A$, $x \in B$, or $x \notin \mathcal{P}(C)$.  I suspect there is no such operation defined, but then how can this be written in formal mathematics?

Comment: For the record, $x\notin C$ is perfectly compatible with $x\in A\lor x\in B$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I improved the question based on your suggestion. I am obviously not a mathematician, but I like learning, so it helps a lot when mistakes are corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard operation for this, but you could define an operation if you wanted to. For example, given a family $\mathcal{F}$ of pairwise disjoint sets and an object $x$, define
$$\mathrm{find}_{\mathcal{F}}(x) = \bigcup \{ X \in \mathcal{F} \mid x \in X \}$$
Note that $\{ X \in \mathcal{F} \mid x \in X \}$ will necessarily be either empty or a singleton.

In the case where $\mathcal{F} = \{ A, B \}$ is a set containing just two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$, this will give
$$\mathrm{find}_{\mathcal{F}}(x) = \begin{cases} A & \text{if } x \in A \\ B & \text{if } x \in B \\ \varnothing & \text{if } x \not\in A \text{ and } x \not\in B \end{cases}$$

Bit like I said, this is not standard notation, so if you wanted to use it then you'd need to define it first.

Comment: why the $\mathcal{F}$ caligraphic notation? Is it personal choice, or is there a convention that sets of sets are calligraphic? I am thinking of the $\mathcal{P}$ notation, which is also a set of sets (also called a family of sets, as I recently found out when making sure I understood your answer correctly)

Comment: what if the family $\mathcal{F}$ is not of disjoint sets, but just any sets? How would the function $find$ need to be changed? I am trying to figure it out by myself, but just saying $\mathcal{X}$ instead of X would not be enough, since $x \notin \mathcal{X}$

Comment: @Andrei: I just use calligraphic letters to denote sets that I want to think of as collections of sets. It's not necessary; you can use '$C$' if you want to. If the sets in $\mathcal{F}$ are not pairwise disjoint then the function I defined would give the union of all the sets containing $x$; in that case, it might be a better idea to remove the '$\bigcup$' from the definition of $\mathrm{find}_{\mathcal{F}}(x)$, so that $\mathrm{find}_{\mathcal{F}}(x)$ is the set of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ that contain $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Now that you said it, it's obvious that dropping the $\bigcup$ is enough, and that the only reason $\bigcup$ was there in the first place was to flatten the collection that contained only one set, which is the one I needed.

Comment: I have one more question though. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is any collection of sets, and the result of the $find$ function depends on $\mathcal{F}$ and $x$. Wouldn't $\mathrm{find}(\mathcal{F},x)$ be a more generic, hence better notation? Otherwise it seems to me that the function is specific to a specific $\mathcal{F}$. But then, I am not a mathematician, and I might not correctly interpret the subscript. Or maybe both are acceptable and interchangeable and a mathematician wouldn't even flinch at this.

Comment: We're defining what $\mathrm{find}_{\mathcal{F}}(x)$ in terms of $\mathcal{F}$ and $x$. It doesn't matter how you write it: if you prefer to write $\mathrm{find}(\mathcal{F}, x)$ then that's fine. There's also no particular reason why we should use the word 'find' (or indeed any word at all): you could also write $\mathcal{F} \triangleleft x$ or $\mathcal{F} \overset{\overset{\star}{\star\star\star}}{\underset{\underset{\star}{\star\star\star}}{\large\star}} x$ or whatever you like.

Comment: If I have multiple values of $x$ that are part of set $Y$, can I just replace $x$ with $\forall (x \in Y) \in X$ . This looks good to me, but I am not sure if I would be understood.